# Fetching List public VM Images in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-compute-api, gcloud-compute

I am using C# Google SDK to fetch the list of public ubuntu or debian VM Images available in Google Cloud.
The response is a long list of VM' having primarily the deprecated State as "OBSOLETE".

When applying the filter for ACTIVE state the response is null , Can anyone help on how to fetch the active images, or if the result returned without filter is correct.

**Scenario 1 . When no filter is applied**

var lstRequest = new ImagesResource.ListRequest(_computeClient, "");
var images = lstRequest.Execute();

## Sample Response

{
"id": "projects/windows-cloud/global/images",
"items": [
{
"archiveSizeBytes": 77493158912,
"creationTimestamp": "2017-11-06T11:38:00.859-08:00",
"deprecated": {
"deleted": null,
"deprecated": null,
"obsolete": null,
"replacement": null,
"state": "OBSOLETE",
"ETag": null
},
"description": "Microsoft, Windows Server, version 1709 Core for Containers (Beta), Server Core, x64 built on 2017-10-30",
"diskSizeGb": 32,
"family": "windows-1709-core-for-containers",
"guestOsFeatures": [
{
"type": "MULTI_IP_SUBNET",
"ETag": null
},
{
"type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE",
"ETag": null
},
{
"type": "WINDOWS",
"ETag": null
}
],
"id": 7068044754301027575,
"imageEncryptionKey": null,
"kind": "compute#image",
"labelFingerprint": "42WmSpB8rSM=",
"labels": null,
"licenseCodes": [
5194306116883728686,
1000226,
2643967004807329741
],
"licenses": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/licenses/windows-server-1709-dc",
"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/licenses/windows-server-core",
"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/licenses/windows-for-containers"
],
"name": "windows-server-1709-dc-core-for-containers-v20171030",
"rawDisk": {
"containerType": "TAR",
"sha1Checksum": null,
"source": ""
},
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-1709-dc-core-for-containers-v20171030",
"shieldedInstanceInitialState": null,
"sourceDisk": null,
"sourceDiskEncryptionKey": null,
"sourceDiskId": null,
"sourceImage": null,
"sourceImageEncryptionKey": null,
"sourceImageId": null,
"sourceSnapshot": null,
"sourceSnapshotEncryptionKey": null,
"sourceSnapshotId": null,
"sourceType": "RAW",
"status": "READY",
"storageLocations": [
"us",
"us",
"eu",
"asia",
"asia",
"eu",
"asia",
"us",
"us",
"us",
"asia",
"asia",
"eu"
],
"ETag": null
},
{
"archiveSizeBytes": 79706428672,
"creationTimestamp": "2017-11-16T12:14:33.128-08:00",
"deprecated": {
"deleted": null,
"deprecated": null,
"obsolete": null,
"replacement": null,
"state": "OBSOLETE",
"ETag": null
},
"description": "Microsoft, Windows Server, version 1709 Core for Containers (Beta), Server Core, x64 built on 2017-11-14",
"diskSizeGb": 32,
"family": "windows-1709-core-for-containers",
"guestOsFeatures": [
{
"type": "MULTI_IP_SUBNET",
"ETag": null
},
{
"type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE",
"ETag": null
},
{
"type": "WINDOWS",
"ETag": null
}
],
"id": 1572352838839848774,
"imageEncryptionKey": null,
"kind": "compute#image",
"labelFingerprint": "42WmSpB8rSM=",
"labels": null,
"licenseCodes": [
5194306116883728686,
1000226,
2643967004807329741
],
"licenses": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/licenses/windows-server-1709-dc",
"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/licenses/windows-server-core",
"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/licenses/windows-for-containers"
],
"name": "windows-server-1709-dc-core-for-containers-v20171114",
"rawDisk": {
"containerType": "TAR",
"sha1Checksum": null,
"source": ""
},
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/windows-cloud/global/images/windows-server-1709-dc-core-for-containers-v20171114",
"shieldedInstanceInitialState": null,
"sourceDisk": null,
"sourceDiskEncryptionKey": null,
"sourceDiskId": null,
"sourceImage": null,
"sourceImageEncryptionKey": null,
"sourceImageId": null,
"sourceSnapshot": null,
"sourceSnapshotEncryptionKey": null,
"sourceSnapshotId": null,
"sourceType": "RAW",
"status": "READY",
"storageLocations": [
"us",
"us",
"asia",
"asia",
"eu",
"asia",
"asia",
"us",
"asia",
"us",
"us",
"eu",
"eu"
],
"ETag": null
},

---

============================================================

Scenario 2: On applying filters

var lstRequest = new ImagesResource.ListRequest(_computeClient, "ubuntu-os-cloud");
lstRequest.Filter = "deprecated.state=ACTIVE";
var images = lstRequest.Execute();

## Response

Null

I am using Google.Apis.Compute.v1  namespace

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: As Sam pointed out `ACTIVE` is a valid state ([link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/deprecate)) but it's unused in the example list, hence the `null` result.

I think because the value `ACTIVE` is invalid.

```sh
gcloud compute images list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--show-deprecated \
--format="value(deprecated.state)" \
| sort \
| uniq

DEPRECATED
OBSOLETE
```

I got results with neither then either of:

```cs
request.Filter="deprecated.state=\"DEPRECATED\"";
request.Filter="deprecated.state=\"OBSOLETE\"";
```

> **NOTE** Image Projects are not the same as GCP Projects
>
> Compute Engine API v1 only surfaces the Image Project as part of an image's `selfLink`
>
> When you `computeService.Images.List(project);`
>
> The value of `project` should be your GCP project not `ubuntu-os-cloud`.
>
> Using `ubuntu-os-cloud` works but it does not filter the results by the `ubuntu-os-cloud` Image Project.

Also, [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is an excellent mechanism to test Google API service calls to ensure you're getting them correct, e.g.:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22ubuntu-os-cloud%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22deprecated.state%3DOBSOLETE%22%7D

Comment: Check this link that states state can be ACTIVE, OBSOLETE, DEPRECATED, DELETED.

Comment: Good find. Although it appears to not be used in this case. No images are returned with that value from the `gcloud` command and that explains why you get `null` in your code.